Go GORM NOT IN query list of ids
I'm trying to run a SELECT * WHERE ID NOT IN (?) query in GORM and it does not seem to work.
The argument for the ? parameter comes from the application and is not a database subquery which would be then easy in this case.
I have to construct the list of IDs within the application code and pass it as an argument to the query parameter.
So I would have something like this in my code:
ids := GetIds()
commaSeparatedListAsString := turnIdsIntoString(ids)
err := Db.Model(&MyTable{}).
    Where("ID NOT IN ?", commaSeparatedListAsString).
    Find(&result).Error

Can I even somehow pass a list of IDs as a query parameter or a comma-separated list of IDs as a string? I tried to pass as parameter "1,2,3,4" but it failed with an error.
Is the a more elegant solution or do I have to create a raw SQL string?

Just use uint64 array instead of commaSeparatedListAsString (when your ID is uint64)

Use Not() func:
Db.Model(&MyTable{}).Not("id IN ?", []int{1,2,3,4}).Find(&result)

Just use IDs directly, GORM will convert ID list to placeholder automatically when querying
var ids []int64
err := Db.Model(&MyTable{}).
    Where("ID NOT IN ?", ids).
    Find(&result).Error

